# Can pyparsing spit out the text which causes a ParseException?

Tags: debugging, exception, text-parsing, string-parsing, pyparsing

Using [`pyparsing`](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/) i try to parse some text with a compound expression like

```
a = pp.Word(pp.alphas).setResultsName('A')
b = pp.Word(pp.nums).setResultsName('B')
c = pp.Word(pp.alphas).setResultsName('C')
expr = a + b + c
```

and `parseString` fails with the Exception

```
ParseException: Expected W:(0123...) (at char 7), (line:1, col:8)
```

So far so good. However, to understand better what's going on, is it possible to ask `pyparsing`/`parseString` to tell me directly what *character from the input string* didn't match? (I can, of course, calculate this myself from the information in the Exception text.)

Additionally is it possible to see *in which sub-expression (a,b or c)* the exception was raised?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pyparsing exceptions include a method markInputline() that will print the last line of the input string and a marker where the exception occurred:

```
import pyparsing as pp
a = pp.Word(pp.alphas).setResultsName('A')
b = pp.Word(pp.nums).setResultsName('B')
c = pp.Word(pp.alphas).setResultsName('C')
expr = a + b + c
try:
    expr.parseString("lskdjf lskdjf sdlkfj")
except ParseException as pe:
    print(pe.markInputline())

lskdjf >!<lskdjf sdlkfj
```

(You can specify a different marker if you don't like '>!<'.)

Here is another method I've used that makes use of the col and line attributes of the ParseException:

```
alphaword = pp.Word(pp.alphas).setName('alphaword')
numword = pp.Word(pp.nums).setName('numword')
expr = alphaword('A') + numword('B') + alphaword('C')
try:
    expr.parseString('sldkj slkdj sldkj')
except ParseException as pe:
    print(pe.line)
    print(' '*(pe.col-1) + '^')
    print(pe)

sldkj slkdj sldkj
      ^
Expected numword (at char 6), (line:1, col:7)
```

A couple of other points:

- I've used setName() to give the expressions themselves names, so that the exception messages are a little more readable. Please note the distinction between setName and setResultsName.
- I've used the call syntax for defining results names. In practice (or just out of laziness) I found the '.setResultsName' method call to really detract from the grammar definition portion of the code. So in place of `expr.setResultsName('xyz')`, you can just write `expr('xyz')`.

Comment: Thanks! Work like a charm. - Using `setName` is good too, but a bit of a pain to write `.a.setname('A')`, `.b.setname('B')` and `.c.setname('C')`... It would be great if the ParserElement` object could inspect the variable name it is referenced by - but that's not easily possible in Python...

Comment: Remember, reserve setName for the expressions (in this example, just alphaword and numword), you don't need to call it every time they are used. But yes, I have looked into various options to autoname expressions, including recalling the call stack and inspecting the line containing the assignment, but they are all fairly dicey, and not reliable across versions or Python implementations. Good luck!